# php delete option is not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

hi i m trying to create a delete conformation box using php in my website but im getting some issues . if i click cancel button also its deleting the row in my database. The index page is designed  in jquery

this is the php code which i have used for delete option?

```
<?php

    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>var x=confirm('Successfully Deleted!')</script>";

    if(x==true)
    {
    echo"deleted";
    include ("dbconnection.php");
$pid=$_GET['pid'];
$sql="DELETE FROM voters where id=$pid";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
echo "<script language='javascript'  type='text/javascript'>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
}
else
{
echo"cancelled";
}
   ?>
```

this is my jquery code...

```
$str.="<thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Card No</th><th>Name</th><th>Mob_num</th><th>Email</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                        $str.="<tr><td><center>".$row['id']."</center></td>";
                        $str.="<td>".$row['vcardno']."</td>";
                        $str.="<td>".$row['vname']."</td>";
                        $str.="<td>".$row['mob_num']."</td>";
                        $str.="<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
                        $str.="<td><center><a class='fancybox fancybox.ajax' href='viewstudent.php?ppid=".$row['id']."' onclick='return update()'><img src = 'images/view.png' height='30' width='30' alt = 'view' title = 'view'/></a><a class='fancybox fancybox.ajax' href='updatestudent.php?ppid=".$row['id']."' onclick='return update()'><img src = 'images/edit-icon.png' height='30' width='30' alt = 'edit' title = 'edit'/></a><a href='delete1.php?pid=".$row['id']."' onclick='return deleteItem()' ><img src = 'images/edit_delete.png' height='30' width='30' alt = 'delete' title = 'delete'/></a></center></td></tr>";
                    }
```

thanks..

Comment: You cannot mix php and javascript code that way. PHP executes on the server, javascript on the browser.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injections; you should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: On top of the client-server code mixup here, I think you should use an HTML `form` tag instead that is fully functioning without JavaScript. Your X variable would be the value of a posted checkbox form element. Only as an extension of a functioning form you should add some JavaScript to enhance responsiveness. That would also make your life a little easier. Another issue is the SQL injection vulnerability in your delete query string. Your unfiltered addition of the `pid` GET variable opens doors for any kind of abuse (consider `pid` being set to `'' OR 1=1` for example).

Answer (score 1):

**x** is a variable of jquery. You can't access it in php code. You need to access it via ajax call (this is the one way).

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use freely javascript then embedding it in php ?

and also you missing `;` in your javascript code.

try this

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
   var x= confirm('Successfully Deleted!') ;
                                           ^^---//you missed this
</script>   
<?php
```

and also **you cant mix PHP and javascript codes.**

You can use this javascript in php in that why but its not advised.

```
 <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
      var x= confirm('Successfully Deleted!') ;
      <?php $abc = "<script>document.write(x)</script>" ; ?> 
</script>   
    <?php
      if($abc==true)
 {   
   ..........
```

Comment: Semicolons are optional in JavaScript, unless two or more statements are on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(x==true)
```

Here you have maid two mistakes. One variables in PHP starts with '$' symbol and You  can not acceess javascript variable in PHP scripts. I think you don't have much idea about **'Client Server architecture'** . PHP script is a server side script which will be processed on Server. Whereas javaScript is Client side script which will be processed on client(Normally on browser).

In your case you can use [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) technology. Make a confirmation dialog before making ajax request to server. And then check the status of the ajax request then make delete success dialog. [Check this sample](http://www.cleverweb.nl/php/jquery-ajax-call-tutorial/) and [tuto](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php)

**[Update]**
Instead of mysql use **mysqli** or **PDO** for good security.